# Ansible Jinja2 and yaml, missing key that is there?

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

## Missing Key that is there !?!

I am working on an Apache template with Ansible.  Ansible calls Jinja2 to create the template.
I have a series of variables stored in a ymal file ( defaults/main.yml ).

### The yaml variable file is

There are other keys then `Block01` i.e `Block02`, `Block03`...  These are treated as dicts.
The `TRAC` is to be a list to iterate through.  Then access the dicts `Dir` `Command` and the list of `Servers` to iterate those.

```py
SSLConfig:
  Block01:
    - TRAC_1117:
      - Directives:
          -  Dir: ['/storage/dav/Provider/Trade-Retail/OPS/software/NOS-400']
             Command: 'SSLRequire  %\{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN\} ne'
             Server: [IDExxxx07000, IDEUxxxxx000]
          -  Dir: ['/storage/dav/Provider/Trade-Development/OPS/software/NOS-400']
             Command: 'SSLRequire  %\{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN\} ne'
             Server: [IDExxxxx000, IDEUxxxxx000, PDEUxxxxP00, PDxxxxxP00]
        Notes: |
          ############# INCIDENT / TRAC : 1117            ################
          # temporarely # because of IA-XD rollout with default-0.9.4.9
          # and pilot phase for GBR
```

It shows I have few nested lists and dictionaries.  That is needed for the flexibility I need for my Ansible playbook.

### The Jinja template

```py
{# Test feed server #}
    {# Location Tract 1117 Apache config #}

{% for trac in SSLConfig.Block01 %}
    {% for key,value in trac.items() %}
        {{ value[0].Notes }}
        {% for directive in value[0].Directives %}
            {% for keydir in directive.keys() %}
                {{ keydir }} =>
            {% endfor %}
            {{ directive }}
            {{ directive.Dir[0] }}
            {{ directive.Command }}
            {{ directive.Server[0] }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
space

{% endfor %}
```

## The error

```
         "FileName": "ms2pro_ssl_testfeed.conf", 
         "TargetLocation": "/home/ansible/ms2pro-test.conf"
     }, 
     "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'Server'"
```

It states the 'Server' key is missing.  I have worked through the code to where Server is the only unknown.  At this point of the code it to get anything on template.  If I remove the `{{ directive.Server[0] }}` out of the template the playbook works.  I have tried without a [] index and various other forms just to access the list.

### Template

```
            ############# INCIDENT / TRAC : 1117            ################
# temporarely # because of IA-XD rollout with os-default-0.9.4.9
# and pilot phase for GBR

                                    Command =>
                            Dir =>
                            Server =>
                        {u'Command': u'SSLRequire  %\\{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN\\} ne', u'Dir': [u'/storage/dav/Provider/Trade-Retail/O
PS/software/NOS-400'], u'Server': [u'IDE000', u'IDEU000']}
            /storage/dav/Provider/Trade-Retail/OPS/software/NOS-400
            SSLRequire  %\{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN\} ne
                                    Command =>
                            Dir =>
                            Server =>
                        {u'Command': u'SSLRequire  %\\{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN\\} ne', u'Dir': [u'/storage/dav/Provider/Trade-Development/OPS/software/NOS-400'], u'Server': [u'IDEU00107000', u'IDEU00120000', u'PDEP00', u'PDE1P00']}
            /storage/dav/Provider/Trade-Development/OPS/software/NOS-400
            SSLRequire  %\{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN\} ne
```

Jinja shows that there is a Server key.  But I can not access it as the key is there when I try to pull the server name PDEXXXX from the variable list.  I used many websites to double check the YMAL formatting.  [Online Yaml Tools](https://onlineyamltools.com/).   I need a second pair of eyes to see if there is a normal reason for this, or I really tripped on a bug.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. ansible 2.9.11, python 3.6.9, Jinja2 2.11.2. The template renders without errors. Meanwhile, I'm not really sure I understand your data structure and how you are trying to use it in your template.

Comment: The error implies that Jinja somehow tries to get the `Server` object via attribute access. This should not happen as in Jinja `directive.Server` is the same as `directive['Server']` (unlike in Python!). You *could* try to check whether `directive['Server']` works.

Comment: For the datastructure: There are other keys then Block01 i.e Block02, Block03... These are treated as dicts. The TRAC is to be a list to iterate through. Then access the dicts Dir Command and the list of Servers to iterate those. 

I will look into attribute access.  That might unlock something useful.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible is a finicky language to work with.
This Jinja2 code works.  Now runs without missing key errors.
Now I can iterate over the TRACs and set which `Block` I use.

```py
{% block FeedCode_ServerList %}
{% for trac in SSLConfig.Block01 %}
    {% for key,value in trac.items() %}

{{ value[0].Notes }}
        {% for directive in value[0].Directives -%}
            <Location {{ directive.Dir[0] }}>
            {% for Box in directive.Servers %}
                {{ directive.Command }} "{{ directive.Servers[loop.index - 1] }}"
            {% endfor %}
        <\Location>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```